# "via Outlook" vs. "in Outlook"

Tags: prepositions

Suppose I am organizing a meeting for my team, here is what I sent to the team

> Hi, team, please check your email, I just scheduled a meeting **in Outlook**.

Should I have used the preposition "via" here?

> ... , I just scheduled a meeting **via Outlook**.

Answer (score 0):

My colleagues usually send e-mails saying they have scheduled or set up a meeting *in* Teams. It would not be completely wrong to say *via* but it would sound slightly unusual.

Location: southern England.

Answer (score 0):

Both phrases are correct but have different nuances.

Via comes to English from [**Latin**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/via), where it means "way" or "road." In English, it means something like "by means of" or "through the channel of."

Thus, **I just scheduled a meeting via Outlook**, means

> I just scheduled a meeting *that will occur* **by means of** Outlook.

This is a fairly literal meaning. It draws attention to the technical nature of Internet communication. In the 1980s-1990s, this sort of talk was natural.

To say ***in* Outlook** reimagines **Outlook** as a physical space that can contain **a meeting**, much in the way *a room* can contain **a meeting.**

This is a more figurative description that is consistent with the graphical user interfaces that characterize modern computing. Concepts such as *directories, windows, buttons, mailboxes,* and so on are convenient representations of ones and zeroes, which are themselves convenient representations of high and low voltages. They are all convenient illusions.

Thus,

> I just scheduled a meeting ***in* Outlook**

means something like

> I just scheduled a meeting ***in a room*** that we call ***"Outlook."***

It suggests a more familiar set of circumstances than **via**. It matches the way most of us experience information technology today.